# error message "too many arguments for format string [12,15"] for a print statement

Tags: python

trying to make this program work but the terminal is showing nothing and when I look at the problems tab it is giving me "too many arguments for format string [12,15"] and "too many arguments for format string [14,15"]

```
from random import uniform, random, choice, sample, shuffle

num_passenger = range(1,51)
time = range(5,51)
num_passenger = list(num_passenger)
time = list(time)
shuffle(time)
time = choice(time)
for num_passenger in range(1,51):

    if(time <= 5 & time >= 15):
        print("{0} {0}".format(num_passenger, time))
    elif(time > 5 | time < 15):
        print("{0} {0}".format(num_passenger, time))
```

Comment: Is it really `&` and `|`, that is *bitwise operations*, you're looking for?

Comment: Your logical conditions don't make any sense. Take this, for example: `time <= 5 & time >= 15` (it should be `and` and not `&` by the way). It is always `False` because a number can't be smaller than 5 and greater than 15 at the same time.

Comment: sorry everyone it was suppose to be| instead of & thanks for the responses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The numbers inside the brackets correspond to the arguments passed to the `.format()` function. So you're using it as if you were only to pass one parameter (since you only have `{0}` in your string), but you're passing two parameters to `.format()`. The correct use is like this:

```
    if(time <= 5 & time >= 15):
        print("{0} {1}".format(num_passenger, time))
    elif(time > 5 | time < 15):
        print("{0} {1}".format(num_passenger, time))
```

[This is a great read](https://pyformat.info/) if you want to learn more about string formatting in Python.

Comment: True, but that's not the reason OP's code is not working.